# instagram feed вывод медиа на сайт

Tags: битрикс, api, instagram

Задача вывести фотографии и видео на сайт (который на битрикс).

Получилось вывести благодаря [этой статье](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/01/display-instagram-feed-website.html)

Но она не совсем подходит для моей задачи. Необходима возможность подписки и оставления комментария прямо с сайта не переходя в инстаграм.

Например пользователь нажимает на фото, оно открывается в popup и там можно подписаться или оставить комментарий. Возможно ли это в принципе?

Может есть какой-нибудь плагин? Подскажите кто знает:)